# IMCE Search module in Drupal 8 is not uploading images from the search results

Tags: imce-file-browser

I am using IMCE Search module which is displaying the results based on the keyword searched. But when I click on any one of the searched images, it is not getting uploaded and instead the pop up window is getting closed without any action.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6mSI.png)

I believe it is a javascript issue but was not able to find a solution for this yet. Appreciate if anyone can provide any help on this.